# Aviary Image not showing in full screen

Tags: android, aviary

I am using Aviary editor in one of my application. Everything is working fine except the image is not showing in full screen. Following is the code :-

```
   public void startAviaryEditor(Uri uri) {
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, FeatherActivity.class);
    newIntent.setData(uri);
    newIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    newIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_IN_API_KEY_SECRET,
            com.frogeducation.frogsnap.constant.Constants.AVIARY_SECRET);
    startActivityForResult(newIntent, AVIARY_EDITOR_RESULT);
}

 Uri uri = mMediaManager.getUri(mAdapterPosition);
                    startAviaryEditor(uri);
```

Following is the screen shot :-
[image: Aviary Image]

Please suggest me how to solve the problem.

Comment: as I know that part is in Avira Library, you have to change layout from lib

Comment: there is no option to change the layout in library. Please suggest some other solution.